# What is the shari'a ruling regarding removing personal belongings when praying in a mosque?

Tags: fiqh, masjid, muslim-practices

I have seen many times that people while praying in a mosque remove their belongings like wallet, watch, spectacles etc and keep it on the ground in front of them and pray salat.
 Is this the right thing to do?
 Do we actually need to remove them and keep them there or is it permissible to keep them in our pockets?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a personal preference & is not Islamic. Maybe for having more concentration.
but it is against what Islam wants:

Qur'an says:

1. > O children of Adam, take your adornment at every Masjid(mosque), and eat and drink, but be not excessive. Indeed, He likes not those who commit excess. [Surat Al-'A`rāf 7:31](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/7:31)
2. > Wealth and children are [but] adornment of the worldly life. But the
   >   enduring good deeds are better to your Lord for reward and better for
   >   [one's] hope. [Surat Al-Kahf 18:46](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/18:46)

So result is:

**A Muslim should take his children and his wealth to mosque.**

Also in a Hadith Fatima Zahra (S.A.) the daughter of prophet prophet said:
every night Imam Ali S.A took one of children to the room that was special for his prayers with himself and did his night prayers.

Also please note: when you take a children to mosque you are responsible to that children do not bother others.

Comment: +1 the end really made me laugh especially when i remember that many parents at our mosque really need to be told that

Comment: @TahirAkram yes it is OK. but in first row two kid should not stand toghether becaus the kids cut the connection of row in Jamaat. but because free space at amount one person has no problem so one child can be. but two child next each other will cut the connection row. the connection by kid is not valid in Jamaat.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not required to take off your adornments as long as they are not excessive, neither it is forbidden to take off personal belonging as long as they are not excessive.

If it helps someone to uphold Salat better then there is nothing wrong to do so. I guess the idea of those who do so is similar to be simple and put aside ephemeral and worldly possessions and belongings while standing in front of God, and to feel you are only a servant (abd) and not superior to other servants of God because of your possessions.